# How to write an nfttables snat rule?

Tags: linux, networking, nat, nftables

Set-up:

1. Linux (tried on LEDE, OpenWrt, Ubuntu 16)
2. iptables disabled (kernel modules unloaded)
3. nftables (tried v. 0.8, 0.8.2)
4. chains and NAT are created according to [official nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)):

   ```
   % nft add table nat
   % nft add chain nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0 \; }
   % nft add chain nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 \; }
   ```

By this set-up, dnat functions as expected, e.g.:

```
% nft add rule nat prerouting tcp dport 15000 dnat 192.168.0.50:20000
```

redirects all incoming TCP packets from port 15000 to 192.168.0.50:20000 and back.

However, no snat rule is processed (neither rule of):

```
% nft add rule nat postrouting counter ip saddr 192.168.0.50 snat 1.2.3.4
% nft add rule nat postrouting counter tcp sport 20000 snat 1.2.3.4:1234
% nft add rule nat postrouting counter ip protocol tcp drop
```

I've tried these rules separately or in variations (oif, ip+tcp, ...) - the packets are still going through unchanged (proved by WireShark) or not dropped. Though:

1. The postrouting chain is processed, since if I remove postrouting chain, dnat (by prerouting) stops to work (as expected).
2. Adding a drop rule to input or output chains works.
3. Adding chains with `type nat hook input/output` according to [A.B.'s suggestion](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=152532769025083&w=2) still doesn't solve the problem.

So, how to write an nftables snat rule?

Comment: What is the firmware the router is currently running? And what's the device make/model?

Comment: cross post: https://serverfault.com/questions/910753/how-to-write-an-nfttables-snat-rule

Comment: so I have to cross comment.. the current nftables implementation requires the creation of the (nat hook) output chain even if not used. eg: https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=152532769025083&w=2

Comment: @A.B: Thanks, good info in general. Unfortunately, in this case doesn't help - I've tried adding input/output/forward chains with no success.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart: I've tried with:

LEDE: SNAPSHOT, r3298-e4297f0, Kernel 4.4;

OpenWrt: SNAPSHOT, r6762-044e84f, Kernel 4.9;

both with NXP/Freescale TWR-LS1021A (ARM) and UHX65A-W (x86-64bit).

Comment: quoting from my link, acked ok by a core nftables team member: "You need to add chain output1 { type nat hook output priority 0; policy accept }" "Yes, unfortunate limitation, it will go away soon though and things
will work without it too.". The wrong information is the nftables wiki

Comment: @A.B 
`table ip nat {
        chain pre {
                type nat hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain inp {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain out {
                type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }

        chain post {
                type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.0.1 snat to 1.2.3.4
        }

        chain out1 {
                type nat hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        }
}`
No luck

Comment: ok. I was so sure that was the cause. sorry for insisting about it (anyway it wouldn't have worked without, so was still worth it). you should edit your question though

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) -- No. Please choose a single Stack Exchange site to host this question, then delete any other duplicate within SE.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Oh, thanks! I will follow the rule.